# I've sent real Monero from Coindirect to my stagenet wallet address, not my mainnet wallet address

Tags: address, stagenet

I've sent real Monero from Coindirect to my local stagenet wallet address and not my mainnet wallet address.

The Monero doesn't show up in either wallet (Daemon/Wallets have synchronized).

Have I lost those funds, or is there a way to retrieve them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stagenet wallet addresses have different prefixes, and so Coindirect's wallet would consider your stagenet address invalid. Even though they didn't alert you to the problem when you entered the stagenet address, their wallet should still automatically fail and not attempt the transaction when the payment attempt is made.

Therefore you should contact Coindirect and ask them to investigate the failed payment.

In the worst case scenario, if Coindirect have a wallet that is not validating addresses prior to constructing transactions, you can still access the funds by creating a mainnet wallet using the stagenet seed.

Comment: The payment was indeed returned as failed, many thanks for the reassurance!